# ios core data cannot find NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Cartdetail' with this code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Hi i'm creating an app that needs to save data in my label content to my core data model which is named as cart.xcdatamodeld and my entity named as Cartdetail.When i press a save button in my app i'm getting following error...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
if (managedObjectContext == nil) { 
managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]managedObjectContext];
}
}

- (IBAction)SaveTest:(id)sender {

ViewController2 *second = (ViewController2 *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cartdetail" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
}


*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Cartdetail''
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x010265a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01444313 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreData                            0x00036ebb +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 187
3   CoreData                            0x0006e9eb +[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 59
4   tablevc                             0x00009c97 -[Description alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] + 519
5   UIKit                               0x00621c5f -[UIAlertView(Private) _buttonClicked:] + 296
6   UIKit                               0x002784fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
7   UIKit                               0x00308799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
8   UIKit                               0x0030ac2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
9   UIKit                               0x003097d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
10  UIKit                               0x0029cded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
11  UIKit                               0x0027dc37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
12  UIKit                               0x00282f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
13  GraphicsServices                    0x01c34992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
14  CoreFoundation                      0x01007944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00f67cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00f64f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00f64840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00f64761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
19  GraphicsServices                    0x01c331c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
20  GraphicsServices                    0x01c33289 GSEventRun + 115
21  UIKit                               0x00286c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
22  tablevc                             0x00001d4a main + 170
23  tablevc                             0x00001c95 start + 53
 )
 terminate called throwing an exception
```

I'm new to iOS..Please help me..Thanks..

Comment: That's quite a bit of code. Try to include only the parts that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't set up your managed object context in AppDelegate!
Take a look at the AppDelegate implementation of the iPhoneCoreDataRecipes example provided by apple: 
[iPhoneCoreDataRecipes example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html)